# Multiple Clients with their own auth, one single IdentityServer?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth, jwt, single-page-application, identityserver4

I have two different SPA clients, A and B. 
The users of A and B come from different sources, A's users are externally authenticated and B's users come from AzureAD.

They both use IdentityServer to authenticate and get a JWT with different claims.

Both clients should be able to use the same API service. The API service has policies to demand specific claims would have. Different policies are applied to different APIs.

So user of client A can access some APIs and a user from client B can access some other APIs (maybe some common ones eventually).

However, if you log in with client A first and then log in with client B, they already have a auth cookie set on IdSrv so the Authorize endpoint just sends them back a JWT with client A's authentication.

**Can I have different clients use different authentication cookies for IdentityServer?**

**Basically I want a single IdSrv instance act as two different instances.**

I could have two domains (a.idsrv.example.com and b.idsrv.example.com) point to the same service (idsrv.example.com) and get cookie isolation, but are there other ways?

Comment: The whole entire point of something like Identity Server is centralized identity, i.e. all the clients use it and it alone for identity services. You can connect Identity Server itself to both a custom auth store and an external provider like AzureAD. Then, your clients can auth to those stores *through* Identity Server, but it makes no sense for them to be authing independently *and* somehow connecting to Identity Server.

Comment: The "sense" is in handling authentication in exactly the same way in all our different applications. The application they use would make the choice for them. I know it's not straight forward, right now I have two different ways of handling auth, one through IdSrv and one through AzureAD. It works fine but I'm looking to see if there's something I'm missing that would make it easier.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. You can hook AzureAD into your existing Identity Server. Then everything auths via Identity Server (which will go through AzureAD, if that flow is activated).